# How to write a doctest for a function that reads from a file?

Tags: python, doctest

my function reads from a file, and a doctest needs to be written in a way independent of an absolute path. What's the best way of wrting a doctest? Writing a temp file is expensive and not failproof.

Answer (score 6):

You could have a parameter that takes the path, marked with underscore to state it's for internal use only. The argument should then default to the absolute path in non-test mode. Named temporary files are the solution, and using a `with` statement *should* be failproof.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import doctest
import json
import tempfile

def read_config(_file_path='/etc/myservice.conf'):
    """
    >>> with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
    ...     tmpfile.write(b'{"myconfig": "myvalue"}') and True
    ...     tmpfile.flush()
    ...     read_config(_file_path=tmpfile.name)
    True
    {'myconfig': 'myvalue'}
    """
    with open(_file_path, 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)

# Self-test
if doctest.testmod()[0]:
    exit(1)
```

For Python 2.x the doctest would be different:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import doctest
import json
import tempfile

def read_config(_file_path='/etc/myservice.conf'):
    """
    >>> with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
    ...     tmpfile.write(b'{"myconfig": "myvalue"}') and True
    ...     tmpfile.flush()
    ...     read_config(_file_path=tmpfile.name)
    {u'myconfig': u'myvalue'}
    """
    with open(_file_path, 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)

# Self-test
if doctest.testmod()[0]:
    exit(1)
```

Comment: This is great. I was able to do the `import tempfile` as `>>> import tempfile` - a separate line above the `with tempfile.Named...` line in the doctest itself, which works as importing doctest doesn't print anything. I believe that way its accessible in the doctest but not in your code, if you're not using the tempfile module elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your doctest could use module `StringIO` to provide a file object from a string.